# Why do include paths in python2 and python3 differ?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, include-path

While trying to make my scons based build system as platform independent as possible I was wondering about the following:

Why does python2 return the include path `/usr/local/include/python2.7`? This path does not contain `Python.h` and building fails if I rely on that path.

#### python2

Use sysconfig inside python2:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:37:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path('include')
'/usr/local/include/python2.7'
```

Gives `/usr/local/include/python2.7`. This is an empty folder.

Call python2-config from shell:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2-config --includes
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7
```

This gives a different path. I was able to find `Python.h` in `/usr/include/python2.7`.

#### python3

Use sysconfig inside python3:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path('include')
'/usr/include/python3.5m'
```

Call python3-config from shell:

```
/usr/bin/python3-config --includes
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m
```

The resulting path `/usr/include/python3.5m` is the same for boath approaches. `Python.h` is located here.

#### anaconda

If I use anaconda python (2 or 3) the paths are also consistent (as with python3).

I already found some workarounds such as placing a softlink to `usr/include` in `usr/local/include` or just throwing away the `local/` in the path, but both do not really look like a nice solution.

*edit:*

Currently the incorrect include path in python2 makes my build system not as platform independend as I would like. Adding an (optional) environment variable `PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH` gives me the possibility to define the correct path, if python2 is used. But a solution where the correct path is always returned would help me a lot (either on python side or using scons-specific functionality).
As my build system is based on scons a

Comment: Why is scons tagged?

Comment: My build system is based on scons. If there is a (scons specific) way to get the correct include path, this would also help a lot.

Comment: What version of SCons and which version of python are you running it with? Please post your relevant SCons logic (SConstruct/SConscript) if you're asking for help with that..

Comment: The thing that really confuses me is the strange behavior of python2-config vs. sysconfig.get_path('include') described above. If there is a scons specific way for circumventing this issue it would also solve my problem, but it does not really answer this question. So you are right that the scons tag is a bit misleading. I will open another more scons specific question tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Thanks to Jeff's answer there is no need for a scons specific solution anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you were picking up a python2-config for another python install? and not the one you were running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python uses an installation scheme that differs depending on the
>   platform and on the installation options.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths

There are various schemes including `posix_local` and `posix_prefix` which determine the location of various installation directories. It seems that `sysconfig` does not actually record which scheme was used to install the particular build of Python -- it only has the build information.

So when you call `sysconfig.get_path()` it guesses the scheme based on the default for the current platform [1]. The Python2.7 `sysconfig` guesses `posix_local` while the Python3 `sysconfig` guesses `posix_prefix` [2].

It looks like both versions of Python are installed using the `posix_prefix` scheme, so you can specify that when you call `sysconfig.get_path`:

```
$ python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('include', 'posix_prefix'))"
/usr/include/python2.7

$ python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('include', 'posix_prefix'))"
/usr/include/python3.5m
```

[1] https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/sysconfig.py#L169

[2] Run `sysconfig` as a script:

```
$ python -m sysconfig | head
Platform: "linux-x86_64"
Python version: "2.7"
Current installation scheme: "posix_local"

$ python3 -m sysconfig | head
Platform: "linux-x86_64"
Python version: "3.5"
Current installation scheme: "posix_prefix"
```

I can't actually find `posix_local` in the `sysconfig` source so not sure where it comes from.

EDIT

I looked into this a bit more and learned that it specific to the Debian/Ubuntu versions of Python; upstream Python doesn't use `/usr/local/` or have a `posix_local` scheme. The Debian packages use a kind of hybrid approach which is the same as `posix_prefix` with the addition of `/usr/local/` for modules.

I haven't found a link the source online, but my local system has this in its Python2.7 sysconfig.py (notice the `FIXME`):

```
def _get_default_scheme():
    if os.name == 'posix':
        # the default scheme for posix on Debian/Ubuntu is posix_local
        # FIXME: return dist-packages/posix_prefix only for
        #   is_default_prefix and 'PYTHONUSERBASE' not in os.environ and 'real_prefix' not in sys.__dict__
        # is_default_prefix = not prefix or os.path.normpath(prefix) in ('/usr', '/usr/local')
        return 'posix_local'
    return os.name
```

The Debian python3 sysconfig.py does away with `posix_local` and uses the same default as upstream python:

```
def _get_default_scheme():
    if os.name == 'posix':
        # the default scheme for posix is posix_prefix
        return 'posix_prefix'
    return os.name
```

You might want to replicate that to be compatible with Mac or Windows:

```
sysconfig.get_path('include', 'posix_prefix' if os.name == 'posix' else os.name)
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviations_from_upstream
https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/python.html#paths